# Ajax with Codeigniter not working

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to make an ajax request and it wont work. This is my code:

```
function loadSingleProductPaso1(div_loading,div_id,index, json,ajaxurl){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: ajaxurl, //the url is http://www.mysite.com/controller/function
    data: "ajax=true&precio="+JSON.parse(json[index]).miprecio,
    success: function(msg){
             ...
            } 
    }
});
```

}

The thing is, when I add a '?' to the data element (data: "?ajax=true&..."), it works, but sends a $_POST['?ajax'] variable.

I really don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: have you tried adding the data to the ajax call using .serialize()? E.g. data: $('#my-form').serialize()

Comment: the data is json objects... if I serialize them, how do I unserialize them later from php?

Comment: if form element is name="is_ajax", then just do $this->input->post('is_ajax'), to see what you got you can just do print_r($_POST)

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean when you say "it won't work." What exactly happens?

Comment: By saying 'it wont work' I mean it doesn't execute the http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use post function,

### like this,

```
$.post(ajaxurl, {
   name : "Test",
   city : "Istanbul"
}, function(data){
   if(data == 1){
       alert("success!");
   }
});
```

---

```
function ajax(){
    if($this->input->post('name') == "Test"){
        echo 1;
    }
}
```